# Get variable in DF with vector to go to several variables

Tags: r, data-transform

I have a dataframe that looks something like this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKTZy.png

I want the dataframe like this:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lWCb.png

How can i do this?

Comment: use `dput(x)` to provide dataset.

Comment: Pictures of data aren't ideal here, because the answer to such a question requires that we know the exact type and structure of what we're dealing with. Could you please include actual data (e.g. the output of `dput(head(my_df))`, where `my_df` is the name of your data frame)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want but I give it a try! So, I suggest a solution using the `str_extract_all()` function from the `stringr` package.

Please find the following reprex below.

**Reprex**

- Your data

```r
DF <- data.frame(Var_1 = c("c(1, 4, 6)", "c(6, 4, 8)", "c(8, 7, 5)"), 
                 Var_2 = c(NA,NA,NA),
                 Var_3 = c(NA,NA,NA))

DF                 
#>        Var_1 Var_2 Var_3
#> 1 c(1, 4, 6)    NA    NA
#> 2 c(6, 4, 8)    NA    NA
#> 3 c(8, 7, 5)    NA    NA
```

- Code of the `DF_dispatch` function

```r
library(stringr)

DF_dispatch <- function(x){
  for(i in seq(nrow(x))){
    z <- str_extract_all(x$Var_1, "\\d+")
    x[i,] <- paste(z[[i]])
  }
  x <- sapply(x, as.numeric)
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  return(x)
}
```

- Output of the `DF_dispatch` function

```r
DF_result <- DF_dispatch(DF)
DF_result
#>   Var_1 Var_2 Var_3
#> 1     1     4     6
#> 2     6     4     8
#> 3     8     7     5
```

- Check of the output

```r
# 'DF_result' is of class 'dataframe'
class(DF_result)
#> [1] "data.frame"

# Each column is of class 'numeric'
sapply(DF_result, class)
#>     Var_1     Var_2     Var_3 
#> "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hello @henrikkh. I hope this answer meets your needs. If it does, please consider marking this answer as "accepted". If not, please let me know what is wrong. Cheers.